# Fail to add filters in API Prometheus query via awscurl python module

Tags: python, prometheus, promql

## Setting

I am trying to query an Amazon Managed Service for Prometheus endpoint to extract some metrics data via a python script. I am using the `make_request` method from the [awscurl](https://github.com/okigan/awscurl/tree/master) module in the following way (cleary this is an example snippet):

```
import awscurl.awscurl as aws

uri = 'https://<SERVICE>-workspaces.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/workspaces/<WORKSPACE_ID>/api/v1/query_range?query=http_request_total&start=1710720000.0&end=1710806400.0&step=1h'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
awscurl_auth_params = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'service': <SERVICE>,
        'region': <REGION>,
        'uri': uri,
        'headers': headers,
        'data': '',
        'access_key': <ACCES_KEY>,
        'secret_key': <SECRET_KEY>,
        'security_token': None,
        'data_binary': False}
r = aws.make_request(**awscurl_auth_params)
```

In this way, I am able to successfully connect to the endpoint and download the data related to the query `query=http_request_total&start=1710720000.0&end=1710806400.0&step=1h`.

## Problem

However, as soon as I try to add a filter (as `statuscode="200"`) in the query using the PromQL syntax (e.g. `query=http_request_total{statuscode="200"}&start=1710720000.0&end=1710806400.0&step=1h`), the same script as above, returns a tedious 400 status code and an annoying `'x-amzn-errortype': 'InvalidQueryStringException'` error.

## Question

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to add filters to prometheus queries through awscurl python library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For Prometheus, the query string must be URL encoded, see Prometheus [HTTP API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/).

The User Guide for Amazon Managed Service for Prometheus explains how to use [`awscurl` to query Prometheus-compatible APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prometheus/latest/userguide/AMP-compatible-APIs.html).

Instead of `GET`'ing which requires that the query string values **already** be URL-encoded; this explains why your example doesn't work, because the query string value should be:

```
http_request_total%7Bstatuscode%3D%22200%22%7D
```

The Amazon example, `POST`s the data using the header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which performs the URL-encoding for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering this.
Yes, the problem was the URL encoding but replacing the query returned an `InvalidSignatureException` error to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a documented issue in the awscurl repo [issues section](https://github.com/okigan/awscurl/issues/169). Replacing the above query string with the URL encoded one retruns an `InvalidSignatureException` error.

The solution that worked for me: removing function `aws_url_encode()` from this [line](https://github.com/okigan/awscurl/blob/master/awscurl/awscurl.py#L334) as explained in this [issue comment](https://github.com/okigan/awscurl/issues/169#issuecomment-1664622134).

Comment: Wouldn't using POST instead of GET (per DazWilkin's answer) be easier than modifying source code of the tool?

Comment: I still get the `InvalidSignatureException` error even if I use POST instead of GET.